# Unable to add image to ZPL through SharpZebra

Tags: c#, asp.net, zpl

I am trying to generate a ZPL file using [SharpZebra](https://sharpzebra.codeplex.com/),And my code looks like this

```
 PrinterSettings p = new PrinterSettings();
   p.PrinterName = "Zebra  105SL (200dpi)";
   p.Darkness = 30;
   List<byte> res = new List<byte>();
   res.AddRange(ZPLCommands.ClearPrinter(p));
   res.AddRange(ZPLCommands.GraphicDelete('E', "SAMPLE"));
   res.AddRange(ZPLCommands.ClearPrinter(p));
   res.AddRange(ZPLCommands.GraphicStore(new Bitmap(@"C:\Assembla\images\logoZpl.bmp"), 'E', "SAMPLE"));
   string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res.ToArray());
   File.WriteAllText("my path"), myString);
```

But for some reason it is not creating a correct image.
output ZPL is this

```
    ^XA^MMT^PR0,12,12~TA000^LH0,0~SD30^PW0^IDE:SAMPLE.GRF^FS^XA^MMT^PR0,12,12~TA000^LH0,0~SD30^PW0~DGE:SAMPLE,800,20,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
830FFFFFE0C1870FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
0007FFFFE0010207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
0007FFFFC0000007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
0007FFFFC0000007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
0007FFFFC0810207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
8207FFFFE0C10207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
^XZ
```

when I view it on online zpl viewer (http://labelary.com/viewer.html), it doesn't creates an image

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried it on a real, not simulated, Zebra printer?

Comment: @Dai Nop. But I have using this online viewer for long time. this works exactly as printer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generated ZPL code contains the ~DG command needed to upload the image to the printer, but does not contain a ZPL command to actually display the image.

I'm not familiar with SharpZebra, but if you add the following right before the last ^XZ, you'll get something to print (although the image looks weird, so I'm not sure if it's the image that you actually wanted to use):

```
^FO50,50^XGE:SAMPLE,1,1
```

Also, you need to remove the commands that set the print width to zero:

```
^PW0
```

Here's a [link](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&zpl=%5EXA%5EMMT%5EPR0%2C12%2C12~TA000%5ELH0%2C0~SD30%5EIDE%3ASAMPLE.GRF%5EFS%5EXA%5EMMT%5EPR0%2C12%2C12~TA000%5ELH0%2C0~SD30~DGE%3ASAMPLE%2C800%2C20%2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A830FFFFFE0C1870FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A0007FFFFE0010207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A0007FFFFC0000007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A0007FFFFC0000007FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A0007FFFFC0810207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A8207FFFFE0C10207FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0%0A%0A%5EFO50%2C50%5EXGE%3ASAMPLE%2C1%2C1%0A%0A%5EXZ) to the live Labelary example with the above changes.

Comment: I have made a check and this is not the image I uploaded, that I can see here. Do you know any other ZPL generating tools rather than sharpzebra where I can make this? My need is like I need to setup a template first and create a lot of ZPL files programmatically using that template

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the method `GraphicWrite`, after the `GraphicStore`:

```
res.AddRange(ZPLCommands.GraphicWrite(50, 50, "SAMPLE", 'E'));
```